# ¿Es correcto esta seleccion?

Tags: php, sql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
SELECT id, concat(ape_usua, ' ', nom_usua) as operador
FROM usuarios
WHERE estado = 'ACTIVO' 
AND cod_perf = 'OP_MORA'
ORDER BY ape_usua ASC
```

Ahora, yo quiero agregar una condición que acepte también cuando.

> cod_perf = 'OP_MORA_CARGA_AVL'

¿Sería correcto si el código queda?

```
SELECT id, concat(ape_usua, ' ', nom_usua) as operador
FROM usuarios
WHERE estado = 'ACTIVO' 
AND (cod_perf = 'OP_MORA' or cod_perf='OP_MORA_CARGA_AVL')
ORDER BY ape_usua ASC
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa cuando lo ejecutas? PD. Procura siempre que preguntes sobre SQL, añadir una etiqueta que indique en qué base de datos se ejecuta el código. ¿Es MySQL? ¿PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No le veo problema en la forma como lo planteas de usar un **`OR`**.

Ejemplo que dejaste:

```
SELECT id, concat(ape_usua, ' ', nom_usua) as operador
FROM usuarios
WHERE estado = 'ACTIVO' 
AND (cod_perf = 'OP_MORA' or cod_perf='OP_MORA_CARGA_AVL')
ORDER BY ape_usua ASC
```

Pero lo mejor seria que utilizaras un **`IN`**.

Te dejo el ejemplo:

```
SELECT id, concat(ape_usua, ' ', nom_usua) as operador
FROM usuarios
WHERE estado = 'ACTIVO' 
AND cod_perf IN('OP_MORA', 'OP_MORA_CARGA_AVL')
ORDER BY ape_usua ASC
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la respuesta y el consejo, que lo voy aplicar!

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo una descripción de los operadores `lógicos`, cuando es `or` si se cumple al menos una condición sera verdadero y si lo cambias a `and` se tienen que cumplir las dos condiciones para que haga tu siguiente proceso.

Solamente seria quitar los paréntesis, por lo demás yo veo muy bien tu `query`.
La precedencia  de operadores logicos es primero `NOT`, `AND` Y `OR`

```
SELECT id, concat(ape_usua, ' ', nom_usua) as operador
FROM usuarios
WHERE estado = 'ACTIVO' 
AND cod_perf = 'OP_MORA' or cod_perf='OP_MORA_CARGA_AVL'
ORDER BY ape_usua ASC";
```

Con `AND`.

```
WHERE estado = 'ACTIVO' 
    AND cod_perf = 'OP_MORA' AND cod_perf='OP_MORA_CARGA_AVL'
```

Con `OR`.

```
WHERE estado = 'ACTIVO' 
    AND cod_perf = 'OP_MORA' OR cod_perf='OP_MORA_CARGA_AVL'
```

Comment: Claro, yo le puse los paréntesis para cuidar que se hiciera primero lo que está dentro de los paréntesis. Sí bien se diferencia entre [or] y [and], no recuerdo la ponderación(creo que se dice así)

Comment: @AgustinAvila precedencia